# How can I list all running Windows processes using Ruby without any additional library?

Tags: ruby, windows, process

I want to list all processes running on my Windows system using Ruby without installing any additional dependency or library that is not already part of Ruby. I have not found any way to do this online. Is there any clean way to do this from Ruby?

Comment: How about `system("tasklist")`?

Comment: or `get-process` if you have powershell... quick @orde, put it as an answer before I do! ;-)

Comment: I would rather not spawn any shell. I would rather use a Ruby API.

Comment: You don't want any dependency or library, you said. so use `system` or backticks.

Comment: I meant I don't want any _external_ library not included in baseline Ruby. If `system` does not spawn a shell I will look into it.

Comment: @Pavling: LOL.  Feel free to edit my answer with the powershell info.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Kernal::system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system)  method to execute a command line argument.  For example:

```
system("tasklist")

    Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
System Idle Process              0 Services                   0         24 K
...
ruby.exe                      1336 Console                    1      9,100 K
tasklist.exe                   944 Console                    1      5,332 K
```

Alternately--as points @Pavling out--you can use `` [Kernal::`] ``(aka backtick), but some find it less readable.  YMMV.

Comment: Is there any way I can do this without interacting with directly interacting with a shell? E.g. some higher-level already-included Ruby module?

Comment: Well, it's a Kernal method, so I don't think you'll get much higher level than that. But--if you use [`backticks`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-60)--you could assign the result because it returns "the standard output of running cmd in a subshell".  `Kernal::system` "returns true if the command gives zero exit status, false for non zero exit status. Returns nil if command execution fails."